# The monitor of Android Studio do not show Logs

Tags: java, android, logging, settings

the monitor of Android Studio do not show Logs.
I have the code:

```
package com.nv.threadpassdata;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "START";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(TAG, "Start");
    }
}
```

And the monitor shows NOTHING:

[image]

In settings the Log ticks are ON.

[image]

I do not use emulator. Instead of emulator I connect my Phone (HUAWEI MYA-L41)
What is the problem? Can anybody find?
Thanks,
Nickolas

Comment: Did you tried it by setting log level to verbose?

Comment: Yes, I tried all choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do on of the following:

1. File>Invalidate Caches and Restart
2. Build>Clean Project then Build>Rebuild Project